# Permutation group notation.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations

[image]

This is from the wikipedia page about parity of permutations. I'm having a little trouble understanding why $(1 3 5)(2 4)$ is equal to $(1 5)(1 3)(2 4)$.

I know they are both supposed to take $12345$ to $34521$. I get why the composition of $3$ does that. But I would have thought $(1 3 5)(2 4)$ takes $12345$ to $54123$. Any help would be appreciated. Just bit confused here about notation and how the operation works.

Comment: You may simply be misunderstanding the cycle notation definition. When we write $\sigma=(a\,b\,c)$, it means that $\sigma(a)=b$, $\sigma(b)=c$, and $\sigma(c)=a$. If you get it backwards, it won't matter for two-cycles like $(i\,j)$, but it will for three-cycles or longer ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us check what happens for each element when applying $(1 \ 3 \ 5)(2 \ 4)$.

- for $1$ the $(2 \ 4)$ leaves it unchanged and then the $ (1 \ 3 \ 5)$ takes $1$ to $3$.
- for $2$ the $(2 \ 4)$ takes $2$ to $4$ and then the $ (1 \ 3 \ 5)$ does nothing.
- for $3$ the $(2 \ 4)$ leaves it unchanged and then the $ (1 \ 3 \ 5)$ takes $3$ to $5$.
- for $4$ the $(2 \ 4)$ takes $4$ to $2$ and then the $ (1 \ 3 \ 5)$ does nothing.
- for $5$ the $(2 \ 4)$ leaves it unchanged and then the $ (1 \ 3 \ 5)$ takes $5$ to $1$.

I am not sure about your reasoning for getting something else.

Comment: "Does nothing" is not a very good way to phrase it I don't think: in the first case, you have $1\mapsto 1$, not "nothing." I think it might be best to simply say, "$1$ maps to itself."

Comment: The informal idea I meant to convey is a dynamical one. The numbers are moved around by the permutation. And, I said it *does* nothing (for $1$). When $1 \mapsto 1$  then $1$ stays unchanged the map does nothing there in the sense that it has no effect relative to the original situation. Depending on the context, I  would also say that the identity map is the map that "does nothing."  I will change it to "stays unchanged." The formulation "maps to itself" by contrast seems overly technical given the context.

Comment: when you say something like "takes 5 to 1" does this mean it takes 5 to the current position of 1 or does it mean it puts 5 in the 1st spot. Because even as I'm following your steps directly, I am still getting 54123. Like if (1 3 5) takes 3 to 5, how come 3 ends up in spot 1?

Comment: @user139985  Now I see the problem. The 1st spot, *not* the current position of 1.

Comment: @user139985 wait, actually after your edited you comment the issue seems still something else. Namely the issue seems to be that you misinterpret the first type of notation. In the notation where you have two row you need to read this by columns. So as you think in fact $3 \mapsto 5$;  because $5$ is what is written *below* the $3$ and this indicates the image of $3$.

Comment: It just clicked, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Viewed as functions, you need to verify that $g=(1 3 5) = (1 5)(1 3)=f$. To prove this you have to prove: $(135)(1) = (15)(13)(1)$, and this is true because $f(1) = (15)((13)(1)) = (15)(3) = 3$, and $g(1) = (135)(1) = 3$. You can verify that $f(2) = g(2), f(3) = g(3), f(4) = g(4), f(5) = g(5)$.